# How install winit in Ubuntu 20.04LTS?

Tags: 20.04, lts, source-packages

Installed the ubuntu 20.04 LTS version but when I attempt to start the gui, no go.  error = unable to locate package winit

Comment: You should try to give a little more information for people to work with. What is it you're trying to achieve? What have you done so far? Where do you get stuck? What versions of software packages are you trying? How did you install the software? How are you trying to run it? etc 
Please use exact logs and error messages and format them correctly. It's always better to give too much info than not enough. You want an answer, not a back-and-forth conversation here.

Comment: Hey airron! What is winit?